# Tmux: equivalent command to screen -d -m -S session_name

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen, tmux

I'm looking at replacing `screen` with `tmux`, currently I use this screen command:

```
screen -d -m -S session_name /root/script
```

Is there an equivalent command for `tmux` that will do the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `new-session` command with the `-d` option is similar to the `-d -m` option in `screen`. The `-s` option corresponds to the `-S` option in screen. Note that `-d` and `-s` are options to the `new-session` command rather than to `tmux` itself.

```
tmux new-session -d -s session_name '/root/script'
```